# Django ManyToMany generic "through" model

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I'm writing a gallery field. The field subclasses `ManyToManyField` and adds its own ajax widget and stuff. I want to make this solution as compact as possible (I mean - I want to write as little code to reimplement this in another projects if possible).

I've decided to create an intermediate table (that provides a 'through' parameter to `ManyToManyField`), which will hold ordering information:

```
class IntermediateModel(models.Model):
    from_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    from_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    from_content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('from_content_type', 'from_object_id')
    to_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    to_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    to_content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('to_content_type', 'to_object_id')
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

The following questions arise:

1. Is it possible to have a "through" model for m2m in django having both foreign keys pointing to a generic relations (like the one above)? If so - how to achieve this?
2. If it's possible to do this - can such model hold generic relations between more than one m2m field? Like: Class <-> Intermediate <-> Student, Gallery <-> Intermediate <-> Photo - both using Intermediate as 'through' model??
3. **EDIT: just tested - I can ;)** Can I use abstract classes with 'through' tables? I figured out - if the above mentioned complex scenario won't work I could just create two abstract classes that provide ordering and some other stuff and then always create normal subclasses to actually build some relations :)

Answer (score 1):

If the difference between the intermediate models is just the way you handle them, maybe you just need to use it with "proxy" models. I mean, using Django model subclassing with a `Meta` option called "proxy" as `True`. This way, you can handle them separately, but having them stored in the same database table (if that is an option to your needs).

Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). Maybe that is what you want. Instead of having 2 database tables with the same structure, you can have 1 table with 2 (or more) ways of accessing and handling them.

Comment: I want to have order field in intermediate model. I'd like to create a generic plug'n'play GalleryField. Having generic intermediate model would spare me some heavy meta class tinkering (auto creating intermediate table). Here are some basic steps to achieve this (imaging.fields.GalleryField and model abstracts in imaging.models) https://github.com/pielgrzym/django-imaging.git